# How can I use the updating local variable in the function, at an if statement outside the function? JS

Tags: javascript, function, variables, animation, scope

I am using an if statement for my animation, but it's outside the function.

Here is an example

```
    var index = 0;
    function animate() {
    index++;
    }
    if (window.index < 100) {
    setInterval(function(){
      animate();
    }, 10);
    }
window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
```

But how do I get the index so it updates the one outside the function?

Comment: why do you need the if statement to be outside of the function?

Comment: So I can have it inside the animation function? If yes then how?

Comment: Just put: `if(window.index < 100) index++;` inside your function

Comment: It solved the issue. Didn't need to use `window.index` read some article that said that would work, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Yea, `index` and `window.index` are two different things. The only reason you'd want it to be `window.index` is if you wanted the variable to be globally available